# "packaged does not exist" when compiling with javac

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, apache-poi, javac

I am nearly complete with my internship work. One thing that is holding me back is compiling

I have a directory with three sub directories: lib, source, class. Within the source sub directory I have a GUI.

I try to run the following command to compile the GUI.

```
javac -cp .:lib\poi-3.11\poi-3.11-20141221.jar -d class\  .\src\GUI\*
```

Contents of some files withing the GUI are dependent upon Apache POI. When I run this command I get the following error:

> src\GUI\CELL_TO_STRING.java:4: error: package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist
>   import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

Here is the imports of my java file CELL_TO_STRING:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
```

There are a few more but for brevity, I'll just list these. I believe this is some issue with specifying the class path to the Apache POI. Apache POI is a pretty big library with tons of jar files. So it will be hard to show you what exactly is in it. But if you could download for yourself to help out, that would be awesome.

From what I have seen on the web is "use maven", "use ant", "use this IDE". IDEs/Build Tools are very useful, I understand that. But I want to know how to properly build java programs through a terminal like ms-dos or shell. Having said that, please don't reply with the mentioned responses on other threads.

Please let me know if I need to give some more information.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  The path separator character on Windows is `;` not `:`.

Comment: @rgettman Yes I am on windows. I just tested: 'javac -cp .;lib\poi-3.11\poi-3.11-20141221.jar -d class\ .\src\GUI*' -- still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Check the [components](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) page of Apache POI. Could you try after including poi-ooxml and poi-ooxml-shemas jars? These are required for ss it seems.

Comment: Tried the following `javac -cp .;lib\poi-3.11\poi-3.11-20141221.jar;lib\poi-3.11\ooxml-3.11-20141221;lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221 -d class  .\src\GUI\*` --still the same error

Comment: Could you include ooxml schemas and xmlbeans jars as well?

Comment: Sorry the first time I included ooxml-schemas but didnt copy it in comment.
 Code: 
`javac -cp .:lib\poi-3.11\poi-3.11-20141221.jar;lib\poi-3.11\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0;lib\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221;lib\poi-3.11\ooxml-3.11-20141221 -d bin  .\src\GUI\*`

Still doesnt work =/

Comment: Is it a ':' before lib? Is there any change in the error message?

Comment: I tried both colon and semi-colon each time, just be safe. No change in the error message.

Comment: You think i may need to include commons-logging, commons-codec, log4j as they are prerequisites for poi?

Comment: You could check if these class files are in the jars.

Comment: I wouldn't leave that one out too.